# Using JavaScript to open a window to an HTML file in MVC 4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to do the following in MVC 4 through a javascript call:

```
window.open('MyView/SomePage.html',..);
```

When I do that now, I get a 404. What are my options?

Comment: Check your path to your .html file, as I don't think it'd be under "MyView". If anything, it should be under a controller.

Comment: Do you mean you are literally trying to open a physical HTML file? If so; your problem is you have the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are trying to show in window.open is the result of a controller action (a view) try doing:

window.open('@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")', ...)

This only works if you are using razor...

The error you are having suggests the view/page you are tring to show in a pop up does not exist. The path must be incorrect.